# Change an element of DenseVector of Breeze Scala Error

Tags: scala, breeze, scala-breeze

I am merely trying to change an element of a DenseVector[Double] from the Breeze linear algebra package. My minimal example looks like this:

import breeze.linalg.{DenseVector}

```
val p = 20
val B = DenseVector.rand(p).map(x=>0.0)
val i=0
B(i)=4
```

Compiling this in intellijidea results in a complicated error
[image]

If I replace B(i)=4 with B(0)=4 then everything works out fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method "update" which does the job.